# Send data to Azure Data cluster from Opentelemetry Collector

Tags: azure, azure-aks

Microsoft Documentation link Used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/open-telemetry-connector

When try to apply configuration from micro soft official documentation. The Opentelemetry collector Crashes.
But According to Microsoft Official documentation it should work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue a few days ago.
Try to upgrade the opentelemetry version to `otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.63.0`
That's work for me.